# How to select one String value from html select option using Jquery JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<select name="state_name" id="select-state" class="lcd-select lcd-border">
  <option value="state_select" selected>Please Select a State</option>
  <%  while(state_result.next()){ %>
  <option>
      <%= state_part1 = state_result.getString("state_abbr")%>                  
      <%= state_part2 = state_result.getString("state_name")%>
  </option>
  <% } %>
</select>
```

I need to select second string using javaScript?
Please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post `processed html` ?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is:

```
<select name="state_name" id="select-state" class="lcd-select lcd-border">
  <option value="state_select" selected>Please Select a State</option>
  <%  while(state_result.next()) { %>
  <option value="<%= state_result.getString("state_abbr") %>">
      <%= state_result.getString("state_abbr") %>                  
      <%= state_result.getString("state_name") %>
  </option>
  <% } %>
</select>
...
<script>
function onLCDLookUp() {
  var select = $('#select-state')[0];
  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624(v=vs.85).aspx
  var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  var abbr = selected.value;
  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534679(v=vs.85).aspx
  var name = selected.text.trim().slice(abbr.length);
  alert(name);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. its really used me very much.